# adding data to local storage depending on the user logged

Tags: jquery, angularjs, local-storage

How can I save the details of the user who is logged in corrently using angularjs?
Eg: if user1 is logged in then the page should display the details belonging to this user only.So how can I add separate keys according to logedin user?

Comment: You should only use one key for logged-in user, and clean it after each logout and\or loginsuccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a simple array of users

```
$scope.users = [
  { id: 1, name: "userOne", email: "userOne@email_provider.com" },
  { id: 2, name: "userTwo", email: "userTwo@email_provider.com" }
];
```

I would then write a function that takes an id and finds the corresponding user, and then stores him in localStorage. Ofcourse, this could be rewritten to take your currentUser (however you have this declared in your code).

```
$scope.storeUser = function (id) {
  var user = _.find($scope.users, function (x) { return x.id === id; }); // _.find is a function found in either underscore.js or lodash. Links to both at the bottom.
  localStorage.setItem('user-' + user.id, angular.toJson(user));
};
```

Then grab the item back from localStorage and set him to $scope.

```
$scope.loadUser = function (id) {
  var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user-' + id));
  console.log(user);
};
```

We could then run both of these functions straight in our control when we initialize, or from our DOM using something like this (where 1 is the id of the user):

```
<button ng-click="storeUser(1)">Store me</button>
<button ng-click="loadUser(1)">Load me</button>
```

This code is probably not tailored to your fit, but it should give you an idea of how you can use localStorage to set and get items with unique identifiers.

Hope this will set you on the right path, good luck :)

UnderscoreJS: https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore

Lodash: https://github.com/lodash/lodash